# Install laravel 4 with composer

Tags: installation, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install laravel with composer, but it's asking me for a username and password. I tried my github credentials but without succes. I also have read the docs and still it's giving me errors.

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\site\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\site\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

When I try to install laravel with composer it's showing me this:

Could not fetch http://nodeload.github.com/laravel/laravel/zip/v4.0.0, enter you
r GitHub credentials to access private repos
The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token stored in C:/Users/AppD
ata/Roaming/Composer/config.json, your password will not be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applica
tions
Username:

And when I try to update it's showing me this:

C:\xampp\htdocs\site>php composer.phar update
Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: I'm not really a Windows user, and i can't tell you much about it, but can you check if 'C:\xampp\htdocs\site\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' exists by opening it from the command line, the different slashes halfway through the filename seems a bit weird, but i don't know how Windows handles this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the extension openssl in your PHP.ini.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me. Only thing is I can't update composer. Giving me this error:

C:\xampp\htdocs\site\laravel>php composer.phar update
Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: You're on windows, just download the [composer installer](http://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe) and use "composer update"

Comment: @MarcLinux little late but if you do php composer.phar self-update it should update.

Comment: I am Using xampp, Composer giving the same open ssl missing error even after removing the ';' of openssl extension in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors are because the composer install hasn't completed as those files are created at the end of the process. As for the actual issue, I think I had it once or twice but just kept trying and it worked. Are you only install laravel or are there other packages? Also make sure composer is up to date.

Comment: I tried to use the command composer create-project laravel/laravel and it's asking me for a username and password. I don't know what to put there. I tried my guthub credentials but without succes. Also i see a directory showing up called laravel and after a second it's gone.

Comment: Yeah once the error occurs it rolls everything back so it will go away. I haven't tried installing like that, wasn't aware you could with laravel/laravel. I always just clone the laravel/laravel repo then install or I use a copy I already clones.

Answer (score 0):

I had openssl enabled both for CLI and APACHE but still had a similar problem where composer was asking for gitHub authentication (username, password). I solved it with this command from [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2366#issuecomment-27130143):

```
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <oauthtoken>
```

Where `<oauthtoken>` should be completely replaced with your token created from  github [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use). 
It may also help to delete your *composer.lock* file and *cache files* (which you can find the directory location of your cache files using the command `composer config --list`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the laravel built-in-server using the `artisan` command...

Just run the following command on your terminal or command promt:

```
php artisan serve --port=portnumber
```

Make sure that you are in the project folder and pointing to the `artisan` file.

Check out this video tutorial...[how to install laravel using composer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4YpBMDl2Zs)